# Software to host Azure IoT solution on a local network

Tags: offline, iot, cloud, azure

I have an Azure IOT solution, but a few of my customers had their own servers and they prefer to have all their applications on their machines and not in the cloud. How to make my Azure IOT solution work without access to the Internet?

FYI, the type of solution I'm talking about is a remote management system of various IOT devices on a local network. But I would like it to work both in the Azure cloud and also locally on some server, if possible.

I don't have this solution yet, but I might build one. It would be a web solution to remotely manage IOTs, usually hosted in the Azure cloud but perhaps some customers would like this web to be hosted on their own local servers. The keywords seem to be Azure IoT Hub, Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service, and IoT Edge